# Laravel markdown mail print raw html

Tags: laravel, markdown

I have this markdown template but it print row html in user mailbox

`Code`

```
@component('mail::message')
# Dear {{$user['name']}},

@component('mail::panel')
New Bank Account has been added to your profile.

|        Bank       |         Acc. No.        |         Acc. Holder         |
| ----------------- | ----------------------- | --------------------------- |
| {{$bank['name']}} | {{$bank['account_no']}} | {{$bank['account_holder']}} |
@endcomponent

Thanks,<br />
{{ config('app.name') }}
@endcomponent
```

`Result`

[image: one]

**any idea?**

Answer (score 1):

try using @component('mail::table')

```
@component('mail::message')
# Dear {{$user['name']}},

@component('mail::panel')
New Bank Account has been added to your profile.

@component('mail::table')
| Bank              | Acc. No.                | Acc. Holder                 |
| ----------------- | ----------------------- | --------------------------- |
| {{$bank['name']}} | {{$bank['account_no']}} | {{$bank['account_holder']}} |
@endcomponent

@endcomponent

Thanks,<br />
{{ config('app.name') }}
@endcomponent
```

Comment: Apparently the issue is with `@component('mail::panel')` removing that will fix the issue.

Comment: i see, glad you found the fix